# How do I file some steel spikes?

Tags: tools, powertools, steel

I have 50 steel rods that are 12in long. I would like to know how can I file the end so that its pointy like the image bellow.

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/8qih7s2l3/hqdefault.jpg]

Comment: They would likely be forged, not filed, especially 50 of them...

Answer (score 3):

State what tools you have access to and it will be easier to give you advice.

A bench grinder is probably the best place to start.

Comment: And state who you are trying to impale.

Answer (score 0):

Bench grinder would make quick work of it. get some leather gloves and some goggles to go with it:

[image]